# MVC how to auto select check boxes whos Label contains a word that user specifies

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

So I've got this popup in my site with a list of checkboxes for filtering purposes. The List can be anywhere from a couple items to a hundred items. Now say the user wants to only select check boxes with the word "create" in it's label. Going through a hundred check boxes looking for creates is unruly and no ones going to want to do it. What I'm thinking is implementing a text box input at the bottom of the popup where the user can input a word, hit select and in the list of checkboxes, only the items that contain that word will be checked.

The first idea that came to mind to do this is use jquery have the button relate to a controller function which will reassess the view model based on that users string. But I'm not if that the best solution. Is there a way to do this in just the view?

Comment: Why dont you reply to the answer???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

Your HTML:

```
<div class="box">
   <input type="checkbox" name="check">
   <label>Create</label>
</div>
<div class="box">
   <input type="checkbox" name="check">
   <label>Other value</label>
</div>
<div class="box">
   <input type="checkbox" name="check">
   <label>Create user</label>
</div>
```

Your JQuery code:

```
$(function(){
    $('.box').each(function(){
        var box = $(this);
        if ($('label', box).html().toLowerCase().indexOf("create") > 0) {
            $('input[type=checkbox]', box).attr('checked', 'checked');
        }
        else $('input[type=checkbox]', box).removeAttr('checked');
    });
});
```

This is a better solution suggested by @AnoopJoshi

```
$("label:contains('Create')").closest(".box").find("input[type=checkbox]").prop(‌​"checked", true);
```

I hope this help!

Comment: Hi @AnoopJoshi, the user wants to only select check boxes with the word "create" in it's label, you have to filter the content of each label.

Comment: $("label:contains('Create')").closest(".box").find("input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked", true); http://jsfiddle.net/by37p/5/

Comment: I think that your first fiddle is the best solution, it's better than mine, post an answer with that fiddle.

Comment: I just wanted to give a suggetion for you.. you can post it along with your answer.  :)

Comment: So sorry for the deployed response. I ended up forgetting about this question and working out a solution much like this one.